# Python-Saving txt information to dictionary containing lists

Tags: python

I’m new to python and I know you can save information to a dictionary in the format:

```
dictionary ={'Albany' : [ 201, 16.9, etc] }
```

But I am trying to get information from a text file to go into that format. Does anyone know how I would do this? Sorry if I am being vague I can try to clarify for anyone if necessary.
Here is part of the text file:

36   1    39857    35436    44278 13.7 12.2 15.2     9271     7566    10976 16.1 13.1 19.1     6123     4832     7414 14.5 11.4 17.6  55778  53673  57883
Albany County                                 NY est13_NY.txt 05NOV2014

36   3     7296     5941     8651 16.7 13.6 19.8     2526     2043     3009 25.6 20.7 30.5     1707     1331     2083 23.5 18.3 28.7  41849  39467  44231
Allegany County                               NY est13_NY.txt 05NOV2014

The first two lines are one line in the text file and what I have to do is compare certain statistics from the top line(child poverty data) and have my program state which county has the highest percent of poverty based on one of the pieces of data and other things based on other pieces of data in the txt file.

For each county this is the data that I need:
The data we care about for each county are:
Position Variable

- 50- 57 Estimate of people age 0-17 in poverty
- 77- 80 Estimated percent of people age 0-17 in poverty
- 134-139 Estimate of median household income
- 194-238 State or county name
- county name includes ' County'. To get rid of it use
  replace(' County','') after stripping trailing white space.

Also I cannot use any modules. 
So far I opened the txt file and then did a for loop reading each line in the file and putting that into a dictionary, but i am not sure how to put it in the format I said above.

Comment: use `f = open()`, `f.read()`, `f.readline()`, etc. to get rows from file, use `split()`, `strip()`, `int()` and put in dictionary.

Comment: if file has structure similar to `CSV` then you can use module `csv` or `pandas` to read it.

Comment: You should add an example of what the file looks like and any code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much information so here is just a demo code help for letting you know how you can achieve that thing :

Generally, people use `collections.defaultdict` for that kind of thing but since you said you don't want any module to import then here is algorithm pattern for this kind of problem :

Let's first understand the actual problem :

> Example Hint :

For these types of list problems there is a pattern :

So suppose you have a list :

```
a=[(2006,1),(2007,4),(2008,9),(2006,5)]
```

And you want to convert this to a dict as the first element of the tuple as key and second element of the tuple. something like :

```
{2008: [9], 2006: [5], 2007: [4]}
```

But there is a catch you also want that those keys which have different values but keys are same like (2006,1) and (2006,5) keys are same but values are different. you want that those values append with only one key so expected output :

```
{2008: [9], 2006: [1, 5], 2007: [4]}
```

for this type of problem we do something like this:

first create a new dict then we follow this pattern:

```
if item[0] not in new_dict:
    new_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
else:
    new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

So we first check if key is in new dict and if it already then add the value of duplicate key to its value:

full code:

```
a=[(2006,1),(2007,4),(2008,9),(2006,5)]

new_dict={}

for item in a:
    if item[0] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
    else:
        new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(new_dict)
```